# Are environments deleted when uninstalling anaconda?

Tags: anaconda

I have `Anaconda 1.10` version on my `Windows 10` laptop.

I have been working with `Anaconda` quite some time and I am have up to 10 environments for different python versions, library versions and projects.

I am not sure if environments are deleted when uninstalling or whether references to environment lost for the new installation of `Anaconda`

Options I have considered:

1. Export environments from actual `Anaconda` version and import environments on the new `Anaconda` version
2. Re-do all environments on the new installation. (This could be tricky)

**How could I uninstall Anaconda and re-install it to do a video on how to install the latest version of `Anaconda`** (without loosing all the environments. )

Answer (score 1):

I just uninstalled Anaconda3 myself and was surprised that the environments were deleted. I would ask for confirmation to save or delete old environments in case you are trying to update something else.

I think you have to resort to exporting the environments as building new ones from scratch are indeed tricky. I know it is a pain, but maybe the Anaconda people will notice this and try to make it less painful.